# sent mail from python CGI - Error

Tags: python, email, cgi

I'm trying to send a mail with from cgi web console using email input field but it fails with below error in apache logs

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/apache-dba/cgi-bin/main.py", line 132, in <module>
    mail()
  File "/opt/apache-dba/cgi-bin/main.py", line 129, in mail
    s.sendmail(me, you, msg.as_string())
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/smtplib.py", line 742, in sendmail
    raise SMTPRecipientsRefused(senderrs)
smtplib.SMTPRecipientsRefused: {'xxx@adp.com/': (501, '5.1.3 Bad recipient address syntax')}
```

But I'm able to run the same code and able to receive the mail from python shell 
Below is the code, this looks like when I run the code from cgi it is trying to convert mailid from 'xxx@adp.com' to 'xxx@adp.com/' resulting syntax error.

```
import smtplib
from email.mime.multipart import MIMEMultipart
from email.mime.text import MIMEText
Emailid = xxx@gmail.com

Link='http://google.com'


def mail():
        me = "GETS.INDIA.DDS.TAM@gmail.com"
        you = str(Emailid)
        msg = MIMEMultipart('alternative')
        msg['Subject'] = "Upgrade Status Link"
        msg['From'] = me
        msg['To'] = you
        text = '%s' % str(Link)
        part1 = MIMEText(text, 'plain')
        msg.attach(part1)
        s = smtplib.SMTP('localhost')
        s.sendmail(me, you, msg.as_string())
        s.quit()

mail()
```

any help will be greatly appreciated, Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like Emailid should be a string. Try surrounding your test email in quotes to make it a string.

```
Emailid = 'xxx@gmail.com'
```